# How to increase YouTube API V3 quote of 10,000 units/day?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I submitted the quota increase form a month ago and went through a lot of back/forth changing minor things on my website. Then I got this message:

"Thanks for your response to the audit form. We will  conduct our audit based on the information you provided.  We will notify you if additional information is needed or when we’ve completed our review."

It's been over a month and I haven't heard anything back. My quota is still 10,000 units/day which is just five or six video uploads.

Can I create multiple projects to increase my limit? I read here that doing that can get you banned..

Any alternative video sharing sites with a simple API? Seems VIMEO may work, but they charge $50/month. That may be affordable if the support is good.

Answer (score 0):

Just heard back from them that my quota increase was approved! So I guess it does take some time.